# Kotlin Regex issue - Not able to parse all the tags

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I wanted to parse a String containing tags like the below into an array of tags using regex in Kotlin. But the regex returns only the first tag instead of an array of tags.

```
private val swiftTagRegex = """@([^:\s]+)\w*""".toRegex()
"// @Flowers @apple @MANGO RedGrape".matches(swiftTagRegex)
return false
```

The same works fine on https://regexr.com/
Not sure what is missed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your actual code that produced a single result could have been, because your supplied code is uncompilable. `matches` returns a `Boolean`.

Anyway, what you need is `findAll`. This returns a sequence, from which you can extract your group using `map` to get your tags.

I'm pretty sure your `\w*` does nothing because all word characters are captured in the previous part of the expression.

```
fun main() {
    val swiftTagRegex = """@([^:\s]+)\w*""".toRegex()
    swiftTagRegex.findAll("// @Flowers @apple @MANGO RedGrape")
        .map { it.groupValues[1] }
        .toList()
        .let(::println)
}

// prints
// [Flowers, apple, MANGO]
```

Comment: `mapNotNull { it.groups[1]?.value }` could be replaced with `map { it.groupValues[1] }`, as matches of this regex must have a value for group 1 anyway.